# Manifest theme/background-color

Tags: manifest, manifest.json

In my manifest.json file I've set my theme-color and background-color

```
{
    "name": "Friends",
    "short_name": "Friends",
    "icons": [
        {
            "src": "/src/images/icons/friends-b-icon-48x48.png",
            "type": "image/png",
            "sizes": "48x48"
    },
        {
            "src": "/src/images/icons/friends-b-icon-144x144.png",
            "type": "image/png",
            "sizes": "144x144"
    },
        {
            "src": "/src/images/icons/friends-b-icon-256x256.png",
            "type": "image/png",
            "sizes": "256x256"
    },
        {
            "src": "/src/images/icons/friends-b-icon-512x512.png",
            "type": "image/png",
            "sizes": "512x512"
    }

  ],
    "start_url": "/index.html",
    "scope": ".",
    "display": "standalone",
    "orientation": "portrait-primary",
    "background-color": "#795548",
    "theme-color": "#795548",
    "description": "Share your moments with your friends",
    "dir": "ltr",
    "lang": "en-US"
}
```

But when I look in Chrome they are gone
[image]

Does anyone know how to fix this?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `manifest.json` the names of the properties use `_` as a separator, not `-`.
You have to change `background-color` to `background_color` and `theme-color` to `theme_color`.